# read_csv() parsing error message, what's the issue?

Tags: r, readr

I'm just fooling around with the different parsing functions in the readr package and came across this error when working with read_csv():

```
read_csv("data frame consisting of fruit types
         lets see if we can skip these first two rows
         type, count, rotten,
         apple, 1, yes,
         banana, 2, no,
         orange, 3, yes", skip = 2
)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  type   count rotten ...4 
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>
1 apple      1 yes    NA   
2 banana     2 no     NA   
3 orange     3 yes    NA   
Warning message:
One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details
```

My df intended to be a 3x3, so having trouble understanding why read_csv() is interpreting it as a 3x4. Anyone have any thoughts or know what could be causing the problem?

I've run problems:

```
problems()
# A tibble: 1 x 5
    row   col expected  actual                                             
  <int> <int> <chr>     <chr>                                            
1     4     3 4 columns 3 columns
```

but having trouble interpreting what and where the issue is.

Comment: Your `csv` contains three `,` like `type, count, rotten,`. Therefore `read_csv` expects another column after `rotten` but there is no data for this column. This is causing your error. Removing the `,` at the end of each row should solve this issue.

Comment: @MartinGal post as an answer, or vote to close it.